# how to pass-by-reference a file to a function?

Tags: c, file, pass-by-reference

I have to do this exercise:

> "in c, create a function that print (file must be opened in "wb") in a file a number (in base 10)".

the exercise gives just the declaration of the function
"extern bool write_integer(const char *filename, int i);"
the problem is that I can't pass a file in the "const char* filename" field because const char* is incompatible with FILE* type. Am I wrong?

Therefore, I think the problem of this exercise is this part: passing to a function a
non-const char* value. But, I can't just simply write (in the main): const char *f; and then FILE *f = fopen...  because it'd be a type redefinition error.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool write_integer(const char* filename, int i) {
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    fprintf(f, "%d", i);

    fclose(f);
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "w"); 
    if (f == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    write_integer(f, 48); 
    fclose(f); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a file to that function in the first place?

Comment: because that's the exercise, passing file/s to this function. Therefore, I tested with an arbitrary file.

Comment: You must not pass "f" of type "FILE*" to the function write_integer. Just pass the file name of type char array.  Also, you are re-opening the file twice.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I checked the extension and it's " .c " so it's not that

Comment: "Just pass the file name of type char array" - could you please explain it better?

Comment: I don't know which file the user (i.e the college test checker (online judge)) will open, so as far as I understand, you mean "converting" the file to an array. Is it right? If it's right, I've to find another way

Comment: You can change the function to `write_integer(FILE* f, int i)` , don't call `fopen` again within the function.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani yeah, you're right. But I can't do that because the test is clear in this point: I have to keep const char function parameter.

Comment: So `int main(void) {write_integer("file.txt", 48); return 0;}` will do the job.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani ah so you mean that filename is a string so can be used as a parameter freely. I thought that it was a file path. I didn't get it

Comment: Yes, you can pass pointers in C. You don't exactly have "pass by reference" in C. It's not clear what the exercise is teaching. Maybe the exercise is about learning `extern` and passing pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird... either you can change the argument of `write_integer` to FILE *. or pass the file name for the function.
And when the file is opened in `wb` mode, you can write only binary value. So, whatever value you send, will be converted to binary and written.

Comment: You can write text when the file is opened with `"wb"`

Comment: Values written to binary streams are not automatically converted to binary. The difference between text streams and binary streams is that, in a text stream, characters may be added, altered, or deleted during I/O to adjust to the host’s conventions for representing text. The most frequent instance of this is changing line-ending indications. This does not change the behavior of `printf` or `fwrite` calls *per se*; they still send the same characters to the stream; there is no added “conversion to binary” for binary streams. Modification of the characters is handled inside the stream software.

Comment: yes. thank you for the clarity. Here, he was passing int, so i said converted. otherwise, there is not direct conversion as such for other types like string or chars.